# How to send on opening connection some additional data from Javascript, like username or time?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, tornado, sockjs

How to send on opening connection some additional data from Javascript, like username or time ?

```
conn = new SockJS('http://' + window.location.host + '/chat', 'websocket');
```

I tried also like

```
conn = new SockJS('http://' + window.location.host + '/chat', 'websocket', {'username': 'x'});
```

On server Python/Tornado side function

```
class ChatConnection(sockjs.tornado.SockJSConnection):
    def on_open(self, info):
        # some code to broadcast data, but info is empty in both cases
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that on connecting but you can send authentication afterwards.

Take a look here: [Can I use query string parameters or cookies to pass data to the server?](http://sockjs-tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-query-string-parameters-or-cookies-to-pass-data-to-the-server)